# Expo FileSystem downloadAsync does not resolve to anything [React Native]

Tags: react-native, expo, filesystems

I'm developing an expo react native app, and try to download a video from django backend using the following code:

```
const downloadVideoAsync = async () => {
const source = "http://localhost:8000/media/videos/video-1.mp4";

const downloadResumable = FileSystem.createDownloadResumable(
  source,
  FileSystem.cacheDirectory + "videos/" + source.split("/").pop(),
  {},
  (downloadProgress) => {
    // Handle download progress if needed
  }
);

downloadResumable
  .downloadAsync()
  .then((response) => {
    console.log("========>", response);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log("========>", error);
  });
```

};

However, it doesn't print any response or error.
Maybe Django is wrongly configured to download videos.

If I try to download the video using curl from the terminal, it works.

What do you think is the problem?
Thank you

Comment: does the progress callback get called?  does the backend have any record of the file access?